# What do the numbers written in the top left corner stand for?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In *The Seven Deadly Sins: The Resurrection of the Command*, there is a number which randomly appears in the top left corner, like:

> 6:48

[image: 6:48]

> 6:49

[image: 6:49]

> 6:54

[image: 6:54]

([Image source](https://steemit.com/anime/@murliza/anime-the-seven-deadly-sins-the-resurrection-of-the-command-2018-winter-poll-episode-4))

What do the numbers written in the top left corner stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the local time in Japan when the show is currently broadcasted. It has nothing to do with anime show.

[A thread on MyAnimeList's forum](https://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=560645) has a quick discussion about this in English.

---

The official term is 時刻出し (*jikoku dashi*, time display). As mentioned before, this is not restricted to anime shows, but more to the TV channel and broadcast time. Usually, this occurs for shows in the:

- morning: from the earliest show up to 10:00
- afternoon: from 11:00 up to 14:00
- evening: from 17:00 up to 19:00 (some as early as 13:00)
- special occasions: New Year's countdown, on-going sports tournament, momentary announcement (news, earthquake, climate).

The reason for the morning, afternoon, and evening shows are most likely to remind the viewers, such as:

- morning: going to work/school before getting late
- afternoon: lunch preparation/lunchtime period
- evening: dinner preparation

---

For this specific example of *The Seven Deadly Sins: The Resurrection of the Command*, the show was broadcasted on local Japanese TV channels ([Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%83%E3%81%A4%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E7%BD%AA_(%E6%BC%AB%E7%94%BB)#%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81%E5%B1%80)):

> - MBC/TBS: January 6 ~, Saturday 6:30-7:00
> - Animax: February 18 ~, Sunday 19:30-20:00

From the example screenshots of 6:48, 6:49, 6:54, it can be deduced that the scene was taken from MBS/TBS, the earliest broadcast for this series. After knowing the timeslot, it's also possible to estimate the relative timestamp for each scene: around 18, 19, and 24 minutes (next episode's preview) into the show.

---

References:

- [Yahoo! Chiebukuro (Japanese)](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1112642331)
- [Yourpedia (Japanese)](http://a.yourpedia.org/wiki/%E6%99%82%E5%88%BB%E5%87%BA%E3%81%97)

Comment: To go along with this, the only reason you're going to be seeing these numbers is if what you're watching was pulled from a TV feed.  That is, if you're not watching it on a TV in Japan, it's almost certainly not an official source.